# Understanding syntax `clustering(G[, nodes, weight])`

Tags: python, networkx

A lot of functions in NetworkX are mentioned like this in the reference. What does this mean starting the square bracket with a comma.
e.g. `clustering(G[, nodes, weight])` `node_redundancy(G[, nodes])` etc. without any first argument.

Is this python syntax or networkx convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clustering(G[, nodes, weight])` simply means that the function `clustering()` takes one required argument `G`, and optionally two other arguments - `nodes` and `weight`. This is fairly standard notation in documentation, regardless of language.

Comment: Ok. I double checked with another example library Pandas and found similar documentation. `GroupBy.nth(n[, dropna])`. Thanks you for helping to understand this.